# Displaying a Soft-Keyboard in Androidthings

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-softkeyboard, android-things

I am opening an APK in androidthings using this code:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = 
manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.lafitness.lafitness.apk");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to make a soft-keyboard available to the app that is opened in this way? Can I programatically enable a soft-keyboard service that is available to all views and intents? If so how would I do this?

I have searched google and stackoverflow with no result for a solution to this. I am running androidthings on raspberry pi 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a EditText view in focus, the soft keyboard will display automatically.
If you want to use a soft keyboard for something else you probably need to create it as a set of buttons and handle each click. It's laborious, but quite straight forward.
All in all it works the same way as in Android

Comment: I havent been able to test yet but my understanding is Androidthings does not have soft-keyboard enabled out of the box.

Comment: Well, it does. Android things does not require a UI, but the UI components are there in case you need them.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity classes you can display soft keypad with some sort of interval.Try to so this in onResume(0 method.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(yourTextBox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    };

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(tt, 200);
}
```